# JQuery: form to calculate total of input fields... but several instances of this form on the same page

Tags: jquery, sum, parent, closest

I've spent more than 20 hours on Stackoverlfow to find a solution to my problem (trying to combine different solutions), but I'm still stuck and definitely need your help!

Basically, I have a simple form with 3 "amount" input fields, and a "total amount" field (sum of the 3 amounts).

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table border="1">

    <tr>
        <td>Amount 1</td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Amount 2</td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Amount 3</td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Total Amount</td>
        <td><span class="total">0</span></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Then the working JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
        $('input').each(function() {
            $(this).keyup(function(){   
                calculateTotal();
            });
        });
    });

    function calculateTotal() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('input').each(function() {
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });

        $(".total").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

However I want to use several instances of the same form within the same page, and I'm trying to have only one "general" JQuery function like my current one, that could work for any form, even on the same page, without mixing fields between forms.

Basically, a function that says "each time an input field is updated, recalculate the total amount and put it in the total field of the CURRENT form/table"

I tried different ways, especially by surrounding the table with `<div>` then find it through "`currentdiv = $(this).prev("div");"` then loop through "current div" using the each function.
But each time either the code is not working, or the total field adds-up amounts from other forms!
I also tried something like the following, without using `<div>`:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('span.total').html(sum.toFixed(2));
or
$(this).closest('span.total').html(sum.toFixed(2));
or even
$(this).closest('span').prevAll('.total:first').html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you show us sample html with different forms and inputs between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little overhaul of your code in general. jQuery does not require you to iterate through all the matched elements in order to attach a listener to them. This is just enough:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $('input.amount').keyup(function(){   
        calculateTotal(this);
    });
});

function calculateTotal( src ) {
    var sum = 0,
        tbl = $(src).closest('table');
    tbl.find('input.amount').each(function( index, elem ) {
        var val = parseFloat($(elem).val());
        if( !isNaN( val ) ) {
            sum += val;
        }
    });
    tbl.find('input.total').html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Note that the `this` keyword in an event handler is not jQuery-wrapped, AFAIK, just as the `elem` parameter of an [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) handler.

Comment: Great! Your code works Derija93! I just put "tbl.find('.total').html" instead of "tbl.find('input.total').html" (because my total field is a span and not an input field). Thanks a lot. I'm going to post the answer with the complete solution.

Comment: I just understood that I cannot answer my own question for the moment... Nevermind: just take my table and copy/paste it as many times as you want. Then use Derija93's code (with "tbl.find('.total').html" instead at the end)... and see the magic! Thanks again, and thanks to ALL contributors!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just pass the table element that contains all the elements in through:

```
calculateTotal(this.parent('table'));//I would set a class on table personally and you need to test this;
```

and then you have a reference which you can use to only get the correct inputs and span i.e.:

```
function calculateTotal(el) {
    var sum = 0;
    $(el).find('input').each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

    $(el).find(".total").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: I dont think you even have to do $(el) you can probably just do el.find(...)

Comment: @11684 yes but the parameter el is a jQuery selection in the above code, so wrapping it up as a jQuery selection is redundant

Comment: yes find is jquery - just replace .find with whatever library or pure js node traversal code you wish. EDIT ah the $(el) part. Rune FS is correct - I have already selected so el is a jQuery object and doesn't need to be $(el) can just be el

Answer (score 1):

This worked wonders to add each individual row

```
$(function() {
    $('.ssizeform').each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            calculateTotal($(this));
        });
    });
});

function calculateTotal(src) {
    var sum = 0;
    var sumtable = src.closest('tr');

    sumtable.find('.ssizeform').each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

    sumtable.find(".qty").html(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
        $('input').each(function() {
            $(this).keyup(function(){   
                calculateTotal($(this).closest('table'));
            });
        });
    });

    function calculateTotal($tab) {
        var sum = 0;
        $tab.find('input').each(function() {
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $tab.find(".total").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a pure jQuery solution working on that [jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/marvinlabs/zcnxH/2/). It will use your markup and find the sum for each table each time you update a field.

```
$("input.amount")
  .keyup(function() {
    total = 0;
    $(this)
      .parents("table")
      .find("input.amount")
        .each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        })
      .end()
      .find("span.total")
      .html(total);
  });​
```